# How to centralize Bootstrap grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my website I have a bar on the top of the page. It contains some music player elements. They will be kept in 3 columns. I would like to keep the bar all back in the top of the page, but the grids stay in the middle.

```
<div class="container navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="height:50px;">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="playerButton pre"></div>
                <div class="playerButton play" onClick="play()"></div>
                <div class="playerButton next"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-8">       
                <div class="waveBar">
                    <div class="waveBarTheme"></div>
                    <div class="waveBarPlayed"></div>

                </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="playerButton unmute"></div>
                <div class="playerButton repeat"></div>
                <div class="playerButton addToPlaylist"></div>
                <div class="playerButton screen"></div>
                <div class="playerButton share"></div>
         </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/danials/b88mc56g/

Any idea to have the bar full-width and grids in the center ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to separate the container(which is what restricts the width) from the navbar. Like this:

```
<div class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="height:50px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>Left box</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>Center box</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>Right box</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b88mc56g/1/)